# LEFT ANTI JOIN SOQL on a non-indexed field

Tags: soql, inner-join

While doing a left anti join in soql on a non-indexed field. The query is failing with QUERY_TIMEOUT.

> 'QUERY_TIMEOUT: Your query request was running for too long.'

Here is my query-

> SELECT ID,Order__c FROM Agent_Credit__c WHERE Order__c NOT IN (SELECT
>   Order__c from Opportunity)

I am running this as daily basis, but success rate is like once in a week.
This is not the exact query what I am running but a similar example.

Comment: The question doesn't contain sufficient information. What is obj2? Is it a list, a sub query, or something else? I suggest you put the original code here.

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure that you are missing `FROM` in your query. Weird that it succeeds even once a week

Comment: @LanceShi edited the query and added the objects

Comment: @Novarg I missed From in the query actually it contains

Answer (score 1):

The use of negative filters like `NOT IN` is just not good for performance. You should see if there's a way to get the data you need in a way that uses positive filters instead.

Any indexed fields you can add positive filters for should improve the situation. For example, if you only want records created this month, you can add:

```
WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_MONTH
```

Whatever changes you make, you can run them through the `Query Plan` tool. Following the same steps you would normally take to [make the query selective](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-make-my-SOQL-query-selective&language=en_US) should yield good results.

Comment: I understand left inner join is better than left anti join, but I have no idea how to apply it in my query scenario. I have edited exact query in the question. Any help on the same will be appreciated.
Thanks